# Exibir um array de objeto em divs

Tags: javascript

Estou enfrentando problemas ao pegar os valores das inputs, armazenar em variáveis e depois passar essas variáveis para um array de objetos. Também gostaria de depois exibir estes valores dentro de cada div separada e no final adicionar todas as div em uma div apenas.

O que devo fazer? Podem me ajudar?

```js
var dia = document.querySelector('#datas').value; //input
var conteudo = document.querySelector('#descricao').value; //input
var valores = document.querySelector('#valor').value; //input
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var osGastos = document.querySelector('#osGastos'); //div

var gastos = {
        data:"",
        descricao:"",
        valor:"",
        set dat(value) {
            this.data = value;
        },
        set descri(value) {
            this.descricao = value;
        },
        set vall(value) {
            this.valor = value;
        }
    };

function exibeGastos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gastos.data.length && gastos.descricao.length && gastos.valor.length; i++) {
        var divElement = document.createElement('div');
        var divElement1 = document.createElement('div');
        var divElement2 = document.createElement('div');
        var divText = document.createTextNode(gastos.data[i]);
        var divText1 = document.createTextNode(gastos.descricao[i]);
        var divText2 = document.createTextNode(gastos.valor[i]);

        
        divElement.appendChild(divText);
        divElement1.appendChild(divText1);
        divElement2.appendChild(divText2);

        osGastos.appendChild(divElement);
        osGastos.appendChild(divElement1);
        osGastos.appendChild(divElement2);
    }
}
exibeGastos();

function addGasto() {
    var dia = document.querySelector('#datas').value;
    var conteudo = document.querySelector('#descricao').value;
    var valores = document.querySelector('#valor').value;

    gastos.dat = dia; 
    gastos.descri = conteudo;
    gastos.vall = valores;

    dia.value = '';
    conteudo.value = '';
    valores.value = '';
    exibeGastos();
}

btn.onclick = addGasto;

function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
    let n = ""
      , h = j = 0
      , u = tamanho2 = 0
      , l = ajd2 = ""
      , o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
    if (13 == o || 8 == o)
        return !0;
    if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
    -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
        return !1;
    for (u = a.value.length,
    h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
        ;
    for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
        -1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
    if (l += n,
    0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
    1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l),
    2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l),
    u > 2) {
        for (ajd2 = "",
        j = 0,
        h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
            3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
            j = 0),
            ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
            j++;
        for (a.value = "",
        tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
        h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
            a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
        a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
    }
    return !1
}
```

```html
<main>
     <p style="position:fixed; background-color: white; width: 100%; margin-top: -20px; font-size: 1.2em;">Despesas</p>
     <section id="osGastos">
          
     </section>
   </main>
   <footer> 
     <input type="number" id="datas" placeholder="DIA" min="1" max="31">
     <input type="text" id="descricao" placeholder="DESCRIÇÃO">
     <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="VALOR" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">
     <button id="btn">OK</button>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não utilizaria divs para fazer essa construção, mas como a sua pergunta foi específica, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
let registros = [];
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let osGastos = document.querySelector('#osGastos'); //div

function addGasto() {
  //recuperando as informações inputadas
  let dia = document.querySelector('#datas').value;
  let descricao = document.querySelector('#descricao').value;
  let valor = document.querySelector('#valor').value;
  
  //montando o objeto com o registro
  let registro = {
    dia,
    descricao,
    valor
  };
  
  //adiciona o objeto para o array
  registros.push(registro);
  
  //executa a rotina de exibição
  exibeGastos();
}

function exibeGastos() {
  //ordenando o array pelo dia
  registros = registros.sort((a, b) => (a.dia > b.dia) ? 1 : ((b.dia > a.dia) ? -1 : 0));

  //limpando o conteúdo da section
  osGastos.innerHTML = "";

  //loop para repopular a exibição dos registros
  for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
    //criando as divs das colunas
    let divDia = document.createElement('div');
    let divDescricao = document.createElement('div');
    let divValor = document.createElement('div');

    //atribuindo o conteúdo
    divDia.innerText = registros[i].dia;
    divDescricao.innerText = registros[i].descricao;
    divValor.innerText = registros[i].valor;

    //ajustando a apresentacao
    divDia.className = "colunaDia";
    divDescricao.className = "colunaDescricao";
    divValor.className = "colunaValor";

    //criando div pai para agrupar os registros da linha
    let divRow = document.createElement('div');
    divRow.className = "linha";

    //adicionando os divs "coluna"
    divRow.appendChild(divDia);
    divRow.appendChild(divDescricao);
    divRow.appendChild(divValor);

    //adicionando o elemento criado
    osGastos.appendChild(divRow);
  }

}

btn.onclick = addGasto;

function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
  let n = "",
    h = j = 0,
    u = tamanho2 = 0,
    l = ajd2 = "",
    o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
  if (13 == o || 8 == o)
    return !0;
  if (n = String.fromCharCode(o), -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
    return !1;
  for (u = a.value.length,
    h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
  ;
  for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
    -
    1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
  if (l += n,
    0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
    1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l),
    2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l),
    u > 2) {
    for (ajd2 = "",
      j = 0,
      h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
      3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
        j = 0),
      ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
      j++;
    for (a.value = "",
      tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
      h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
      a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
    a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
  }
  return !1
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.linha {
  width: 100%;
}

.colunaDia {
  width: 65px;
}

.colunaDescricao {
  width: 170px;
}

.colunaValor {
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <h2>Despesas</h2>
    <section id="osGastos"></section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <form action="">
      <input type="number" id="datas" placeholder="DIA" min="1" max="31">
      <input type="text" id="descricao" placeholder="DESCRIÇÃO">
      <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="VALOR" onKeyPress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">
      <button id="btn" type="reset">OK</button>
    </form>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Gostaria fazer algumas observações em relação ao código apresentando e apontar alguns erros...

O principal dele é a confusão que você fez em criar um objeto para armazenar os valores, mas tenta navegar por ele como se estivesse trabalhando com três vetores diferentes para cada propriedade.

```
for (var i = 0; i < gastos.data.length && gastos.descricao.length && gastos.valor.length; i++) {
        var divText = document.createTextNode(gastos.data[i]);
        var divText1 = document.createTextNode(gastos.descricao[i]);
        var divText2 = document.createTextNode(gastos.valor[i]);
```

`JavaScript` é uma linguagem dinâmica, não faz muito sentido você declarar a estrutura do objeto e definir seus setters no caso onde não há complexidade alguma.

Veja que:

```
var gastos = {
        data:"",
        descricao:"",
        valor:"",
        set dat(value) {
            this.data = value;
        },
        set descri(value) {
            this.descricao = value;
        },
        set vall(value) {
            this.valor = value;
        }
    };
```

Virou apenas isso:

```
  let registro = {
    dia,
    descricao,
    valor
  };
```

Quando a variável e o atributo possuem o mesmo nome, basta a declaração para que o nome e valor sejam setados. Essa já é uma das vantagens em não declarar duas variáveis como `Element`,`Element1`, `Div1`, `Div2` e etc.